# mongoid: message&reply: Is this a good structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have to implement a message model which would have replies for itself. I ended up something like this:

```
class Message

   include Mongoid::Document

   belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :snt_msg
   belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :rcvd_msg

   embeds_many :replies, :class_name => "Message"
   embedded_in :message, :inverse_of => :replies
end
```

and this for user:

```
class User

include Mongoid::Document

has_many :snt_msg, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :sender
has_many :rcvd_msg, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :recipient
end
```

Is that Ok to work with it, or is there any well-structure design for that?

Comment: Looks fine to me. My only suggestion would be to change the sames of `:snt_msg` and `:rcvd_msg` to `:sent_messages` and `:recieved_messages` respectively, since that fits a little better with Rails naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks, i did it. But when i want to insert some reply i get `Mongoid::Errors::InvalidPath`.

Comment: have you tried `redursively_embeds_many` http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common

Comment: Used already. Doesn't work, but thanks.